# Postgresql - Syntax Error at or near ","

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I'm trying to set up a prepared statement and execute it using the `database/sql` package, but it is giving me this error saying `2018/07/24 08:34:44 pq: syntax error at or near ","`, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Errorf("error Connecting to DB")
}

defer db.Close()

stmt, err := db.Prepare(`INSERT INTO "TEST_TABLE" ("pid", "name", "brand", "sku", url, price, image, "dateInserted", "dateUpdated") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) on conflict ("pid") do update set "dateUpdated" = EXCLUDED."dateUpdated"`)
defer stmt.Close()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

_, err = stmt.Exec(obj.Id, obj.Name, obj.Brand, obj.Sku, obj.Url, obj.Price.Regular, obj.Image, time.Now(), time.Now())

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the statement executed? You should find it at least in the PostgreSQL Server logfile.

Comment: With postgres use positional parameters e.g. `($1, $2, $3, ...)`, not question marks. `?` are a mysql thing.

Comment: @mkopriva: the syntax for parameters is defined by the language (and the driver) running the SQL statements. "SQL" itself has no notion of parameters PL/pgSQL uses indeed `$1`, but in Java (JDBC) you would need to use `?` as well.

Comment: The first step in debugging something like this, is to try to run the statement manual with the SQL client of your choice that usually gives more details on the error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see, my bad for saying it's postgres/mysql dependent. But it is the case that the "default" drivers for postgres and mysql in Go, do indeed use `$N` and `?` respectively.

Comment: @mkopriva your comment about using ($1, $2, $3) indeed works!!!